# Проверить совпадения в ArrayList

Tags: java

Есть коллекция:

```
List<PlaceCell> placeList = new ArrayList();
```

Класс PlaceCell.java:

```
public class PlaceCell { 
   private String name;
   private double position;
   private int x;
   private int y;
   ...
}
```

Необходимо проверить есть ли в коллекции экземпляры класса у которых поля x и y совпадают с полями x и y в других экземплярах класса PlaceCell. Поля name и position могут быть одинаковыми у нескольких экземпляров класса. То есть надо написать метод который будет возвращать true или false в зависимости от результата проверки. Думаю надо бежать цикл в цикле, но почему-то не получатся.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение *в лоб*:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(List<PlaceCell> placeList) {
    for (int i=0; i<placeList.size(); i++) {
        PlaceCell firstPlaceCell = placeList.get(i);
        for (int j=i+1; j<placeList.size(); j++) {
            PlaceCell secondPlaceCell = placeList.get(j);
            if (firstPlaceCell.getX() == secondPlaceCell.getX()
                    && firstPlaceCell.getY() == secondPlaceCell.getY()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Здесь первый элемент коллекции сравнивается со всеми последующими, затем второй со всеми последующими и так далее.

Подразумевается, что `PlaceCell` имеет соответствующие геттеры.

Но, повторюсь, это самое простое и очевидное решение. Существуют более лаконичные варианты, вроде того, который опубликован в [соседнем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659198/220996) ответе.

Comment: Спасибо я столько с этим "промучался"

Answer (score 3):

Переопределяем `equals()` и `hashcode()`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof PlaceCell) {
        PlaceCell another = (PlaceCell) o;
        return x == another.x && y == another.y;
    }
    return false;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * 31 + x;
    hash = hash * 31 + y;
    return hash;
}
```

Проверяем наличие:

```
Set<PlaceCell> tempSet = new HashSet<>(placeList);
if (tempSet.size() < placeList.size()) {
    //есть дубликаты
}
```